# With python ElementTree, how to add a node to a tree having namespace?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

The tree I'm adding nodes to uses a namespace:

```
xmlns:ns0="http://someplace.net/xml/"
```

Before inserting the child, you must reach the parent node first, and in my case `findall()` gives me the parent node that looks like this:

```
<ns0:parent xmlns:ns0="http://someplace.net/xml/" someattrib="some value">
```

I tried to construct a child node like this:

```
node = ET.Element('mytag')
```

or

```
node = ET.Element('ns0:mytag')
```

or

```
node = ET.Element('ns0:mytag')
node.set('xmlns:ns0', "http://someplace.net/xml/")
```

Then

```
parent.extend(node)
```

But the node was nowhere to be found in the resulting tree. None of the three methods worked.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I should use `ET.SubElement(parent, node)` to replace `ET.Element` and forget about `.extend()`.

I should also remove the hard-coded namespace prefixes from the tags.

After making the above changes, it worked as expected.